# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.api.common.ExecutionConfig

Tags: java, apache-flink

The local IDE starts normally, docker deployment to Linux startup error and Java version 21

> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.api.common.ExecutionConfig[[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/imByP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pFQ7Z.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TKhtA.jpg)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
> at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
> at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:534)
> at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:513)

help help help help help

Comment: You may want to read [ask]